# Find probability of a single occurrence in map_query in pgmpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

I am working on a bayesian network which looks like this

[bn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML252.png)

I want to find the probability of P(+j|-e) which means that finding the probability that JohnCalls is true given earthquake is false. Here is the code that I wrote which includes the network

```
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel
from pgmpy.factors.discrete import TabularCPD
from pgmpy.inference import VariableElimination

def buildBN():

    #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  VERY IMPORTANT  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    # MAKE SURE to use the terms "MaryCalls", "JohnCalls", "Alarm",
    # "Burglary" and "Earthquake" as the states/nodes of the Network.
    # And also use "burglary_model" as the name of your Bayesian model.
    ########-----YOUR CODE STARTS HERE-----########
    burglary_model = BayesianModel([('Burglary', 'Alarm'), 
                                ('Earthquake', 'Alarm'),
                                ('Alarm', 'JohnCalls'),
                                ('Alarm', 'MaryCalls')])
    
    # Parameter definition
    cpd_Burglary = TabularCPD(variable='Burglary', variable_card=2, 
                            values=[[0.999], [0.001]])
    cpd_Earthquake = TabularCPD(variable='Earthquake', variable_card=2, 
                            values=[[0.998], [0.002]])
    cpd_Alarm = TabularCPD(variable='Alarm', variable_card=2, 
                            values=[[0.999, 0.06, 0.71, 0.05], 
                                    [0.001, 0.94, 0.29, 0.95]], 
                            evidence=['Burglary', 'Earthquake'], 
                            evidence_card=[2, 2])
    cpd_JohnCalls = TabularCPD(variable='JohnCalls', variable_card=2, 
                            values=[[0.95, 0.1], [0.05, 0.9]], 
                            evidence=['Alarm'], evidence_card=[2])
    cpd_MaryCalls = TabularCPD(variable='MaryCalls', variable_card=2, 
                            values=[[0.99, 0.3], [0.01, 0.7]], 
                            evidence=['Alarm'], evidence_card=[2])

    burglary_model.add_cpds(cpd_Burglary, cpd_Earthquake, cpd_Alarm, cpd_JohnCalls, cpd_MaryCalls)

    ########-----YOUR CODE ENDS HERE-----########
    
    # Doing exact inference using Variable Elimination
    burglary_infer = VariableElimination(burglary_model)

    ########-----YOUR MAY TEST YOUR CODE BELOW -----########


    ########-----ADDITIONAL CODE STARTS HERE-----########

    print(burglary_infer.query(variables=['JohnCalls'], evidence={'Earthquake': 0}, elimination_order='MinFill', joint=False)['JohnCalls'])










    ########-----YOUR CODE ENDS HERE-----########
    
    return burglary_infer

buildBN()
```

I am getting the following output

```
Finding Elimination Order: : 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Eliminating: Burglary: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Finding Elimination Order: : 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Eliminating: Alarm: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Finding Elimination Order: : 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Eliminating: Alarm: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Finding Elimination Order: : 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Eliminating: Alarm: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Finding Elimination Order: : 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Eliminating: Alarm: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 64.00it/s] 
Finding Elimination Order: : 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
Eliminating: Burglary: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s] 
+--------------+------------------+
| JohnCalls    |   phi(JohnCalls) |
+==============+==================+
| JohnCalls(0) |           0.9489 |
+--------------+------------------+
| JohnCalls(1) |           0.0511 |
+--------------+------------------+
```

I am getting the answer as output but what I think +j means to output only JohnCalls(1)

I am submitting it but it is still showing error of malformed feedback which means that there is some error in my code. The code is compiling and I am getting output but I think it is not in the form of the expected output thus the malformed feedback.

Is there any other way to extract only JohnCalls(1). Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which pgmpy version you are on. But from `0.1.16`, there is a `get_value` method in `DiscreteFactor` which returns a single value for the specified state. In your example, you can change the last line to something like this:

```py
>>> query_cpd = burglary_infer.query(variables=['JohnCalls'], evidence={'Earthquake': 0}, elimination_order='MinFill', joint=False)['JohnCalls']
>>> query_cpd.get_value(JohnCalls=1)
0.05109565
```